# conditionnal order by with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-order-by

I want to do a query with a statement like that with the doctrine query builder in Symfony

```
SELECT * FROM events e ORDER BY e.languageID = :langId DESC, e.categoryID IN (:catIds) DESC
```

How can I add a conditionnal ordering in the the query builder. 
Is there a bundle with any extension that allow to do that kind of things ?

I really would like to avoid a raw query

Comment: What is this doing anyway? Either you order by languageID or you don't - or do you want to filter the result? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: doctrine has methods for that in QueryBuilder class - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods

Comment: @LBA this expression put the founded languageid in the first position. it works and it's pretty convenient.

Comment: @SergeiKutanov i'll try with some combinations of    ->add('where', new Expr\Comparison('u.id', '=', '?1'))
   ->add('orderBy', new Expr\OrderBy('u.name', 'ASC')); it could work